# How to convert from Array<String> to String[] in Java

Tags: java

I have to get a part of my content provider query in a String[] format.  Currently I use:

```
        String[] selectionArgs = {"",""};
    selectionArgs[0] = Integer.toString(routeScheduleID);
    selectionArgs[1] = runDate.toString();
```

But in this case I have an unknown number of elements.

How can I change the number at runtime (or use something like an Array and convert back to String[].  Is this possible?

Comment: ...Use a `List<String>`?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to convert between lists and arrays; check `Arrays.asList` and the `List` API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `List<String>` to get your data and then get the array out of it:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add(Integer.toString(routeScheduleID);
lst.add(runDate.toString());
lst.add(...);
...

String[] selectionArgs = lst.toArray(new String[lst.size()]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use List for this. A List of Strings like this - `List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list to populate the data then convert the list into an array:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(item1);
list.add(item2);
...

String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> selectionArgs = new ArrayList<String>();

selectionArgs.add(Integer.toString(routeScheduleID));
selectionArgs.add(runDate.toString());
selectionArgs.add(...).
 ...........

String[] array= selectionArgs.toArray(new String[selectionArgs.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> selectionArgsList = new ArrayList<String>();
selectionArgsList.add("string1");
selectionArgsList.add("string2");

String[] selectionArgs = new String[selectionArgsList.length];
selectionArgsList.toArray(selectionArgs);
```